# Is net.ipv4.vs.timeout_timewait used also for IPv6?

Tags: linux, tcp, ipv6

Does this setting for TCP `net.ipv4.vs.timeout_timewait` apply only to TCP connections established over IPv4 or does it also apply to TCP connections established over IPv6?

I have found this for example

```
/sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.vs.timeout_timewait=60
Sockets will linger in TIME_WAIT state for no more than 60 seconds.
```

But no information if it is applicable to IPv6.

Comment: From a quick glimpse into `net/netfilter/ipvs/ip_vs_ctl.c` and from down there into `net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_proto_tcp.c` and companions, it seems that there are no `#ifdef`'s to rule out usage of this when running IPv6. Which kind of makes sense as most of the netfilter code is shared by both IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

Some kernel IPv4 options also apply to IPv6. From the latest stable [kernel sources](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/include/net/tcp.h?id=refs/tags/v3.16.1), we see that the TIME_WAIT interval is already set to 60 seconds:

```
#define TCP_TIMEWAIT_LEN (60*HZ) /* how long to wait to destroy TIME-WAIT
                                  * state, about 60 seconds */
```

In Linux operating systems this option is not configurable. Please check [the following discussion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.network/244411) for more details.

I would also recommend reading [this article](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html) to get some understanding how to configure the TCP TIME_WAIT properly.